# How rebuild children navigator page with Provider in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, provider

### I doesn't understood very well to apply in my case any solution.

I have a `BudgetsPage` that holds the `Consumer` notifier of budgets updates

This `BudgetsPage` has a `ListView` with `BudgetContainer` component.

```
ListView.separated(
...
  itemBuilder(context, index) {
    return BudgetContainer(
      budget: bdg
    );
  }
)
```

When clicked on this `BudgetContainer` it navigates to another page that opens `BudgetOpened` page.

```
Navigator.push(
  context, MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => BudgetOpened(
       budget: this.budget,
       currentValue: currentValue,
       valueLimit: valueLimit
    )),
);
```

The `BudgetOpened` use `budget` variable to show all information.
But, when I set a Provider.of and `notifyListeners` the infos aren't updated.

I would like `BudgetOpened` to rebuild and update the budget infos.

In theory, the `budget` variable is passed through all navigators and components, including `BudgetOpened`.

Comment: Is the budget variable passed made available everywhere only through Provider.of ? Check the logic of the budget variable Provider to be sure you are properly updating the budget. You could be using double equals where you wanted to make an assignment. Is the BudgetOpened widget a Consumer too?

Comment: I'm getting the `budget` variable on Notifier of `BudgetPage` and passing through Widgets.
`var budget= notifier.monthsBudgets[this.indexMonth].budgets;`

and passing to `BudgetContainer` eg: 
`return BudgetContainer(budget: budget); `
And `BudgetContainer` is passing to another page and etc.

Comment: `BudgetOpened` is a StatelessWidget wihtout Consumer

Comment: So you might have to refactor to maybe pass the index (instead of the budget itself) across all these widgets. Then in each widget (BudgetContainer or BudgetOpened), use Consumer/Notifier with the index to get the budget. Do it this way so that the changes will reflect as you want. With you current configuration, the Dart `budget` object given across the children widgets don't have the "self-auto-update" ability through Provider. Do you understand?